# Howto release a package with system dependency ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros?

Tags: ros, gazebo, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a ROS package with the run dependency `gazebo_ros` (specified in package.xml).  When I release this package for Indigo the resulting debian package depends on `ros-indigo-gazebo-ros`.

Is it possible to make debian package depend on `ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros`?

Regards,

Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226336/howto-release-a-package-with-system-dependency-ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-11**:
There are `rosdep` keys for `gazebo` and `gazebo5`, but not for `gazebo6` ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/70cf0267a7e04a4172d55de4f783c117bc49d9ba/rosdep/base.yaml#L743-L757)). At least those will probably have to be added.

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-02-11**:
Thank you for this information. Can I add the rosdep keys for gazebo6 myself (e. g. with a patch) or is there any official support team I could ask for this feature?

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-03-03**:
As a workaround I removed the run_depend `gazebo_ros` and `gazebo_ros_plugins` from package.xml. Users will have to install `ros-indigo-gazebo6` and `ros-indigo-gazebo6-plugins` manually to be able to run the launch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The policy for adding keys to the rosdep database is that the packages need to be available from the ros repository or from the standard upstream sources.

There are rules for gazebo and gazebo5 because they are available in the upstream. When packages land in upstream we can add them to the rosdep database.

Note that your dependency on gazebo_ros does not actually interact with the rosdep database. The gazebo_ros package is a ROS package in the rosdistro, which is why it ends up with `ros-indigo-` in the prefix.

The gazebo team maintains newer versions of gazebo built into debians such as gazebo 5 and 6. Some details are at: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions

You can also locally modify your rosdep sources to add new rules for gazebo as mentioned on this question by @jose-luis-rivero : http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8598/how-to-install-ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control-with-gazebo-5/ however they cannot be added to the default since they rely on the packages.osrfoundation.org repository.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-02-11**:
The upcoming ROS version *Kinetic* for Ubuntu Xenial will have Gazebo 7 and will allow you to release against it as a dependency if that helps.